# Two elements on two opposite sides

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, element

How to create div with 2 element's (text and img) on two oppoiste sides? Length of text is variable (it's a list of months to select). So the text should be on the left side of the div or "p" and img should be on the right. Between them is gap. Like on this page:
https://zapodaj.net/acb40b1461eaf.jpg.html

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve] *in the question itself*, not **only** on a third party site.

Comment: read about css float

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways to do this, either using [float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) or a [margin](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) on each object in the container.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS-Property [Float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) could help you!

```css
.parent {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
 }
 
 .left-child {
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 margin: 10px;
 background: #DDDDDD;
 
 float: left;
 }
 
 .right-child {
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 margin: 10px;
 background: #DDDDDD;
 
 float: right;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="left-child"></div>
<div class="right-child"></div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using float as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .left {
        float:left;
        }
        .right {
        float:right;
        }
        img {
        margin:0.5em;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <p class="left">Text will come here</p>
            <img src="" width="" height="" class="right" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please specify image properties.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, including margin, float or even position: absolute in some cases, but it's worth noting that there is a fairly new set of css properties - flex:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
</div>
```